# importing table data in SQL from Excel - maintain carriage returns

Tags: sql-server, excel

I've imported data into a SQL temp table from an Excel spreadsheet (using wizard). One column in excel contains an address with carriage returns:

```
Address line 1
Address Line 2
Address Line 3
```

But when I update my master table from temp table and view in database application the address is "`line 1 Line 2 Line 3`", without carriage returns. How can I keep the formatting from excel to address lines on separate lines?

Comment: The grid in SSMS won't show carriage returns. Have you checked how they're shown with results to text?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack, but ended up replacing carriage returns in Excel with '|' and then used

```
REPLACE(field_name,'|',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

in SQL to replace '|' with carriage return and line feed. Worked like a charm.